# Css not imported into html

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My folder structure is like this

index.html
css/styles.css

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-custom">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css/styles.css

```
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.panel-default > .panel-heading-custom {
    background: #ffaa00; color: #aaa;
}
```

However, it appears that the panel colour does not change at all. Apparently it works on this jsfiddle and i copied and pasted the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/a0y0qmns/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include file in this sequence.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
```

`styles.css` after `bootstrap.min.css` because bootstrap css overwrite the style css.

Comment: Omg Thanks a lot. I would accept this answer when i can. Could i ask how do i change the width of the panel?

Comment: Just give `width: 200px;` to `.panel { }`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply a case of bootstarp over-riding your custom css files. In the head section of your html place your styles.css below bootstrap.css. Then in styles.css you have to use the exact same selector for the element you want to override.

Answer (score 2):

just change `.panel-heading-custom` to `.panel-heading`

```
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/a0y0qmns/1/